# Storing File Paths in a Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

### Background Information

I am working on a project that has file path fields that are either a "one to one" relationship (Invoice object has only a single file is allowed) or "one to many" relationship (a Claim object has many files that can be added to it).

### What I Have So Far

I currently have two ideas.

**1) One Database for All Files**

I have a [Claim] Database

```
Claim (PK) --- Name --- Address
1              Joe      Some Place
```

I have an [Invoice] Database

```
Invoice (PK) --- Vendor --- FilePathID
100              12         1
```

And an [Attachments] Database

```
UID (PK) --- Claim --- Description --- FilePath
1            NULL      Invoice         path\to\invoice
2            1         Receipt         path\to\receipt
3            1         Image           path\to\image
```

This would work in the following way:

The [Invoice] file would be explicitly defined ([Attachment] ID 1 in this case) in the [Invoice] object. Then files would be attached to the [Claim] object by a linking number (Claim 1 in the case above) in the "Attachments" database. This way we can do a query to list all attachments for [Claim] one, but at the same time keep the [Invoice] file in the same [Attachments] database linked by the UID number for the file. This allows all uploads to be mapped in a single database.

My only concern with this method is that on the file that is uploaded for an [Invoice] the Claim field is left to NULL.

**2) File Paths Are Stored In Multiple Databases**

This is almost identical to the above example but instead of linking the FilePath in the [Attachments] database it is defined directly in the [Invoices] database. Like this:

I have a [Claim] Database

```
Claim (PK) --- Name --- Address
1              Joe      Some Place
```

I have an [Invoice] Database

```
Invoice (PK) --- Vendor --- FilePath
100              12         path\to\invoice
```

And an [Attachments] Database

```
UID (PK) --- Claim --- Description --- FilePath
1            1         Receipt         path\to\receipt
2            1         Image           path\to\image
```

This method allows for the Claim field in the [Attachments] database to never be NULL, but it separates the area where the [Attachments] FilePath is found.

I am very torn between the two methods at this point. Is there a preferred method or best practice to do this or is it really just what one feels comfortable doing?

#### Update

We are having to do this for at least 4 objects. Not just two.

Thanks very much in advance and any help is very much appreciated,

Brandon

Comment: I think your term called **I have a Claim Database** mean's **I have a Claim Table**, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is "best practice", but here's an Option 3:

[Claim] table:

```
ClaimID (PK) --- Name --- Address
1                Joe      Some Place
```

[Invoice] table:

```
InvoiceID (PK) --- Vendor
100                12
```

[Attachment] table:

```
AttachmentID (PK) --- Description --- FilePath
1                     Invoice         path\to\invoice
2                     Receipt         path\to\receipt
3                     Image           path\to\image
```

[ClaimAttachment] table:

```
ClaimID (FK) --- AttachmentID (FK)
1                2
1                3
```

[InvoiceAttachment] table:

```
InvoiceID (FK) --- AttachmentID (FK)
100                1
```

If you need the database to enforce that an invoice may only have one attachment, put a unique constraint on the Invoice column in the InvoiceAttachment table.

Alternatively if you want to only have one table to handle the attachment relationships, you could do something like this:

[AttachmentRlshp] table:

```
AttachmentID (FK) --- EntityID --- EntityType
1                     100          Invoice
2                     1            Claim
3                     1            Claim
```

Comment: Yeah we thought about this option too but we have to do this for more then just two objects. We would have too many linking databases if we went this route. I do like the suggestion though.

Comment: Well, instead of two separate attachment tables then, you could do one table with three columns, the attachment ID, the foreign entity ID, and an entity type indicator. This requires that all your ID fields be of the same type, and you also lose the ability to have the database enforce referential integrity. I'll edit my answer to show this alternative.

Answer (score 4):

If i where facing the problem, I would have a base table called `Document` for all document-like entities, having shared properties of all documents.
 
Having this base table, `Attachment` table will have a `one-to-many` relation to `Document` table.
Other document-like entities such as `Invoice` or `Claim` will have a `one-to-one` relation to the Document table.

[image: draft model]